# C while(false) loop

Tags: c, while-loop, lexical-analysis

I was looking at a lexical analyzer code and i came across this:

```
while ("false")
{
    c = fgetc(f);
    switch (state)
    ...
```

I tested it and the code works, it produces correct results. Why does the loop run if there is `false` condition? Shouldnt the loop never run?

Comment: AntonH i dont understand, what pointer are you talking about?

Comment: Hunter McMillen what does that mean? Do i have to include <stdbool> or something like that?

Comment: `"false"` is a string literal, the only way to access this literal is via a pointer to the literal. The literal exists, therefore `while("false")` cannot evaluate to while `while(0)`.

Comment: This looks like either some kind of educational or a very stupid code. Where did you get it from?

Comment: This is slightly more clever than `#define false true` but still looks like a troll post IMO.

Comment: @zett42 "3.6 biturbo" isn't even a real username.

Answer (score 5):

The loop will work, like in `while(1)`, `while(100)`, `while("something else")`.
I think that the author of this code has strange sense of humor.

Answer (score 3):

`"false"` is a string with a non-zero address. The address evaluates to `true` in the `while` condition.

Answer (score 2):

The `while` control structure only accepts Boolean parameters.

If it doesn't get Boolean parameters, the parameter is evaluated to a Boolean. In this case, "false" is a string, and it evaluates to a `true` value. Only `0`and `false`actually mean false.

Comment: I think `NULL` and `'\0'` also mean false. :-)

Comment: @ZhigangAn `NULL` is just a token representing 0 and the decimal value of a nul byte is guaranteed to be 0 :)

Comment: Yes, I agree with @George NULL just represents 0 and 0 and null byte equate to false.

Comment: @George Yes, that's true. I was joking.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the while loop to never run, the condition should be the number `0`, or the keyword `false` without any apostrophes, quotation marks, etc... enclosing it.

A `0` or `false` is a Boolean-type value. However, passing `"0"` is not the same as just `0`, because "0" is a string value. Anything else inside the condition of the for-loop apart from `0` or `false` will cause the `while()` to run (unless you've specified some condition, but that's irrelevant to *this* question).

Therefore, since "0" is a string, which is **not** equal to `0`, the compiler passes sees it as a non-false value (or non-zero value), and runs the `while()` loop.

If you do `while(0)` then the `while` loop will not run even once.